# Setting a Grid as ListBoxItem.content

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I'm trying to create a grid, and set it as the content for a `ListBoxItem`. I'm doing this in C# in `PrepareContainerForItemOverride()` method of `ListBox` class for performance reasons.

```
protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
{
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, object);
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    ... adding stuff to the grid ...
    ListBoxItem lbItem = element as ListBoxItem;
    lbItem.Content = grid;
}
```

I can set some string to the content, but not the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lbItem.Content = grid;
lbItem.ContentTemplate = null; // Added one line to set ContentTemplate to null
```

This had to be done, even though there was no ContentTemplate definition in xaml. ListBox had some default content template that was messing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the grid as the content, maybe you just can't see it ?

Because this works fine :

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var grid = new Grid();
            grid.Children.Add(new TextBox { Text = "Test" });
            var lbItem = new ListBoxItem();
            lbItem.Content = grid;

            _myListBox.Items.Add(lbItem);
        }
```

Comment: What kind of "stuff" do you add to the grid ?

Comment: A few images. The grid works otherwise, just not in this context within the ListBox.PrepareContainerForItemOverride()

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ContentTemplate of the Item. 
You can set in xaml and it is much cleaner.

Comment: I would use it if we had less items, but in this case this is faster